# How to join an Active Record object with json from external API in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to combine data from an external API with data in my database.

I have a Table in my DB called **Teams**, which include an *ID* column (primary key) but also an *external_id* column (with reference to ID in the external API I’m using) 
When I use the external API to fetch a list of Teams, (for example to see all Teams that belong to a specific League) I want to be able to join that Team Resource with the corresponding Team in my database (or create it if it does not exist yet)

How can I best accomplish this?

Currently, I do it like this. But I imagine that there is a more efficient way to do this?

leagues_controller.rb

```
 def show
 @teams_by_league.each = Externalapi.teams_by_league(123)[“data"]
 end
```

leagues/show.html.erb

```
<% @teams_by_league.each do | league_team | %>

<% @team = Team.where(external_id: league_team[“id"]).first %>

<%= league_team[“name"] %>
<%= league_team[“position"] %>
<%= link_to @team.name, team_path(@team) %></td>

<% end %>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest you do all of your logic in the controller action and only display the final resulting data in the view. Then, moreover, depending on how often this external data changes, I'd suggest running a cron script/job to regularly fetch and update your DB with external API data and then only display data from your database in your view instead of the extra API call. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Ok, thank you!

If I move this logic into the controller, how would that look? Should I still loop through the response and assign the @team variable in every loop or is there a better/cleaner way to do it?

Comment: I'd suggest saving the attributes you want from the API to your matching record in the database (do this in the model, something like a `Team#save_api_attributes!` method).  You are relying on the API to respond (and quickly) when your view loads. If you save the attributes to your database, you can control pulling the records you want when you want them.

Answer (score 0):

Ther is super cool `Array` method `Array#index_with` which indexes each array element with some other value as a key.

In you case key would existing or newly created `Team` instance
and value is `league_data`.

Here's code example:

```rb
teams_by_league_data = Externalapi.teams_by_league(123)["data"]

# this will return a hash where key is a Team instance and value is `league_team`
@teams_by_league = teams_by_league_data.index_with |league_team|
  Team.where(external_id: league_team["id"]).first_or_create do |team|
    # create team if it does not exist and assign other attributes
    team.name = league_team['name']
    team.position = league_team['position']
  end
end
```

I agree with @Mark who commented that this should go to controller or better create a service object to do this heavy lifting.